# How to select a region of an UIImage and then create a new one out of it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-graphics

is there an easy way of selecting a region of an UIImage Instance and then creating a new image out of it? I tried it using a pan-gesture Recognizer for getting the coordinates that the user selected. But with this option there is now visible feedback and i also have to transform the coordinates. Is there maybe a nice plugin or best practices for doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
// retrieve the current graphics context
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// render view into context
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
// create image from context
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   image=[self cropImage:image];
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   - (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)oldImage {
       CGSize imageSize = oldImage.size;
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake( imageSize.width,imageSize.height - 150),NO,0.); //set your height and width
          [oldImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake( 0, -80) blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.];
          UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
          return croppedImage;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([bigImage CGImage], cropRect);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```